# Azure Synapse dedicated sql pool not showing data objects in synapse studio

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am working on [Tutorial 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-spark) of this doc from Azure Team where [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-spark#load-the-nyc-taxi-data-into-the-spark-nyctaxi-database) in a `Dedicated SQL pool` (that actually is also a database - as item 2 of Tutorial states) creates a database named `nyctaxi` with a table `nyctaxi.trip` as follows:

```
%%pyspark
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS nyctaxi")
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("nyctaxi.trip")
```

Then Tutorial 5 creates another table `NYCTaxiTripSmall`. After completing these tutorials, I can see (on the Data Hub of the Synapse studio) my `Dedicated SQL Pool` as shown below. But when I click on any database object folder it does not show any db object (tables, external tables etc.) and instead, it shows a red cross sign (as shown below).

**Question**: Why I am not seeing the db objects (described above) in the Dedicated SQL pool below.

**Remarks**: Please note that I also created `DataExplorationDB` db and an external source in [tutorial 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-sql-on-demand#create-data-exploration-database) using serverless SQL pool - and, as shown in yellow below, I can see that db and its objects. So why same is not true for Dedicated SQL Pool db? I have also restarted the Dedicated SQL pool and it's online. But still no db objects are showing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Spark database the tables aren't automatically added to your Dedicated SQL Pool.  You can add them as External Tables if you want, but there's no automatic metadata sync between Spark and Dedicated SQL Pool.

Synapse does create a serverless "Lake Database" corresponding to your Spark database, which you can use from SQL Scripts or access with SQL Server reporting tools.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out - as I do see those tables inside `Lake Database` section that is created above `SQL Database` section in the `Data Hub` of Synapse studio. But, in what cases, one would be able to see the db tables (for example) inside `Tables` folder of `DedicatedSQLPool` folder (shown in yellow in image above?

Comment: Only when you create a table using TSQL in a SQL Script or from SQL Server Management Studio.